Sourcetree completed with errors but there is no error?
I was cloning my very large repo from github with ssh. But after many hours it's done with an empty folder and gave this message:
git --no-optional-locks -c filter.lfs.smudge= -c 
filter.lfs.required=false -c color.branch=false -c color.diff=false -
c color.status=false -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c 
core.quotepath=false -c credential.helper=sourcetree clone 
git@github.com:Foobar/Foo.git /Users/MyMacUser/Foo 
Completed with errors, see above

What is the error? I really don't understand.
I tried to clone it with HTTPS before, but then it gives different errors. That's why i switched to ssh.
I'm using MacOS 14.5

Why is it taking hours? Probably it should not. Have you checked your internet connection? Is your git installation valid? If that s not the case, then fixing http errors may be less complicated than resolving ssh errors since the latter requires configuration steps at the first place, so why not trying to solve these first? In case you are not able to resolve them using online resources, I would recommend that you make a new Post .
